COMPAT locale provider will be removed in a future release
For a long time, when to compile the TeX files, the texstudio 4.7.3 editor based on MacTeX 2024 warns me that
sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter <clinit> WARNING: COMPAT locale provider will be removed in a future release


Then what should I do? Please state as specific as possible or step by step. By the way, I searched on the internet, and found the webpage which may be related to the problem. But I don't know what should I do.

If you have a question about a specific editor, maybe it would be a good idea to mention which editor you use?

Which version of texstudio do you use? I don't get such a warning

Please include the which version of texstudio you use. It might also help if you would show a screenshot of were you see the message.

please add a screenshot

4.8.2 is the current version, maybe check if the problem is still there with an up-to-date texstudio https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/4.8.2

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz A screenshot is uploaded. And I will try the latest version of texstudio.

This might be a message from one of the tools you use to compile your document rather than from texstudio. How do you compile your document?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex and biber -l zh__pinyin %. I think it's -l zh__pinyin that invokes the locale.
